# OSx bash script to crop, move and merge two images

Tags: image, macos, bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have two images of identical size that I want to programmatically crop, move and merge using a bash script in OSx El Capitan, preferably using something like ImageMagick.

The images are equal size, and I want to create a resulting image of the same size. In the resulting image, I want the first image (`1`) to be moved 25% of it's width to the left, while the second image (`2`) is moved 25% of it's width to the right. `1` should then be cropped 25% from it's right edge and placed on top of `2`.

To explain it in a more graphical way, here are my two original images:

[image]

The entire operation looks something like this, where the red frame represents the resulting image boundary, and the yellow frame represents the part of `1` that should be cropped away.

[image]

The resulting image should look like this:

[image]

How would I accomplish something like this in a bash script in OSx? I read a guide on ImageMagick layers, but when I try to run my bash script (which uses a `MIFF:-` stream to join the layers) I just get the output (at least that's what I think it is) in the terminal instead of as a new file.

If someone can help me get started (or if you're up to it provide a working example) I'd be grateful.

Comment: The `-` in `MIFF:-` likely means "standard output. If you want it in a file either redirect it to a file with the shell or try `MIFF:filename`? That said do you want a file that something *other* than imagemagick can read because I would expect `miff` won't give you that.

Comment: If I understood the guide I linked to, one could use a `MIFF` stream to merge multiple layers together before finally outputting the stream to a file? That's what I was trying to do, but obviously I must be doing something wrong. I'd like the output file to be JPEG.

Comment: Like I said `MIFF:-` is almost certainly sending to standard output so you can then do something with that data via a pipe or similar idea. If you want that sent to a file then either add `> somefile.miff` to the end of the command to redirect the output to a file or try `MIFF:somefile.miff` to see if that works (it seems like it should). How you then process that into a jpeg later I don't know (but it sounds like you have a guide that tells you that?).

Comment: So you want the central 50% of image 1 abutted to the left 50% of image 2?

Comment: You should attached your code to the post so we can see what you have tried. miff is a special Imagemagick file type and as said miff:- is an output. if you want to save the image you need to give it a filename instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I start with this as image 1 (400x300px):

[image]

and this as image 2 (400x300px):

[image]

I think you want this (400x300px):

```
convert \( 1.png -gravity center -crop 50x100% \) \
        \( 2.png -gravity west   -crop 50x100% \) +append result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! Just had to change to `gravity center` on the second image as well, and now it's working beautifully. Had no idea it could be done so easily.

Comment: Excellent - glad it worked for you. Good luck with your project.

Comment: If that's the case, you can probably simplify it to `convert -gravity center 1.png 2.png -crop 50x100% +append result.png`